# Mailing settings not displaying

Tags: civimail, email

For some reason none of the mailing settings seem to be accessible for me anymore. When I go to e.g. Administer > CiviMail > Mailer settings all I get is a blank screen, and it's the same for other mailing settings as well. We haven't been able to find why the settings aren't visible anymore so any advice would be much appreciated.
We're running on CiviCRM 4.7.15 and Drupal.

Thanks,
Saeunn

Comment: Have you made any recent changes such as updating CiviCRM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes when unexplainable things like this happen, it helps to just clear all the caches. Administer > System Settings > Cleanup Caches

If you use drush, `drush cc civicrm`. If that doesn't work, you could delete everything inside of the templates_c folder.

`rm -r /[path/to/drupal_root]/sites/default/files/templates_c/*`

Answer (score 1):

We have seen instances where civimail produced a blank screen after we hit rollback issues related to a CiviRule that was set to create an Activity after an online Contribution was added. (and changed some backtrace stuff)

Just mentioning this as an example of weird and wonderful and seemingly unrelated 'changes' can trigger failures such as this (ie angular pages not loading)

This is not a technically 'deep' answer but might give you an 'ah ha' moment if you can think of other things that have been added since you last successfully sent an Mailing.